# UIImagePickerController overlaying an image on top of it correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

**About this question:**

- **Device**: iPod touch 4th gen (640 * 960 retina display resolution)
- **OS**: iOS 6
- **Dev Kit:** XCode 5.0.2
- **Source code I try to modify:** [PhotoPicker example](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html)
- **Aim**: add image on top of UIImagePickerController view

**Description:**

I am modifying the [PhotoPicker example](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple with the aim to add a custom PNG image displayed above the camera lenses before taking the picture. The image will indicate where the user has to put his/her face.

The image below shows what I get and what I want. As you can see it seems that the original image does get rescaled and **becomes way too big**.

[image]

The main method that is called when the "camera" button is tapped is the following. I modified it adding a **UIImageView** subview to **imagePickerController**, where I initialized the UIImageView with a UIImage containing the original 640*960 image.

When I run this piece of code on my iPod 4th generation (640 * 960) it seems that the image that is scaled a lot. How can I fix my code below to allow the image to **overlay perfectly the camera?** (the dot should appear in the center and the black borders in the borders)

```
 - (void)showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    if (self.imageView.isAnimating)
    {
        [self.imageView stopAnimating];
    }

    if (self.capturedImages.count > 0)
    {
        [self.capturedImages removeAllObjects];
    }

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        /*
         The user wants to use the camera interface. Set up our custom overlay view for the camera.
         */
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;


        // Set rear camera
        imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

        /*
         Load the overlay view from the OverlayView nib file. Self is the File's Owner for the nib file, so the overlayView outlet is set to the main view in the nib. Pass that view to the image picker controller to use as its overlay view, and set self's reference to the view to nil.
         */
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
        self.overlayView.frame = imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
        imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
        self.overlayView = nil;

        UIImage * imageOfFaces = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo border" ofType:@"png"]];

        UIImageView * imageViewOfFaces = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageOfFaces];

        [imagePickerController.view addSubview:imageViewOfFaces];
       [imageViewOfFaces sizeToFit];
    }

    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

---

**Full size images:**

Here is the PNG image I would like to overlay (is 640w * 960h pixel):

[image]

However this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Does the image have @2x suffix? Did you check the content mode of the image view?

Comment: Yep, that was it! :) Could you put it as answer or do you think I should delete the question as too trivial?

Comment: Yeah thought so :) I think deleting have something to do with your stats. I'm not sure though.

Comment: will you please explain what is self.overlayView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your image has the retina suffix like this:

```
image@2x.png
```